# How to draw a filled circle?

Tags: c++, c

I'm creating bitmap/bmp files according to the specifications with my C code and I would like to draw simple primitives on my bitmap. The following code shows how I draw a rectangle on my bitmap:

```
if(curline->type == 1) // draw a rectangle
{
    int xstart = curline->x;
    int ystart = curline->y;
    int width = curline->width + xstart;
    int height = curline->height + ystart;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for(y = ystart; y < height; y++)
    {
      for(x = xstart; x < width; x++)
      {
        arr[x][y].blue = curline->blue;
        arr[x][y].green = curline->green;
        arr[x][y].red = curline->red;
      }
    }

    printf("rect drawn.\n");
}

...
save_bitmap();
```

**Example output:**
[image]

So basically I'm setting the red, green and blue values for all pixels within the given x and y field.

Now I'd like to fill a circle by knowing its midpoint and radius. But how do I know which pixels are inside this circle and which pixels ain't? Any help would be appreciated, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A point lies within the bounds of a circle if the distance from the point to the center of the circle is less than the radius of the circle.

Consider a point (x1,y1) compared to a circle with center (x2,y2) and radius r:

```
int dx = x2 - x1; // horizontal offset
int dy = y2 - y1; // vertical offset
if ( (dx*dx + dy*dy) <= (r*r) )
{
    // set pixel color
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked flawlessly. I never imagined it actually would be that easy to compute the pixels to fill!

Comment: As an exercise, you might want to try anti-aliasing the edges.  That means taking into account the width of a pixel, and shading the boundary when a pixel is very near but not exactly inside the circle.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try the midpoint algorithm, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) on wikipedia.